# how can I init look_sdk by client_id and client_secret, not by file

Tags: looker

I use looker_sdk to call looker API by python, and init it by

```py
import looker_sdk

p = Path(__file__)
sdk = looker_sdk.init31(p.parent / f"looker/looker.ini")
```

but I need to put the client_id and client_secret in azure key vault,not in a local ini file,so how can I init looker_sdk by client_secret and client_secret

Answer (score 0):

The SDK supports configuration through a `.ini` file on disk as well as setting *environment variables* (the latter override the former).

For any `.ini` setting you can use an environment variable instead. It takes the form of `LOOKERSDK_<UPPERCASE-SETTING-FROM-INI>` e.g. `LOOKERSDK_CLIENT_SECRET`.

From [developers.looker.com [Configuring the SDK]](https://developers.looker.com/api/getting-started)